# IBM Blockchain Platform - Unable to invoke transactions

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

I am working through the IBM tutorials to better understand blockchain technically. I got stuck on Step A4.6: Click 'myAssetExists' to open the Transaction View. For some reason when I connected to the Fabric Gateway in VS Code it did not bring in the drop down menu for 'demo-contract@0.0.1' under the Fabric Gateway section.

[Here is what it looks like in my VS Code. IBM tutorials show that it should say MyAssetExists, CreateMyAsset, etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n37i4.png)

Then I am receiving an error that says it could not get the metadata for smart contract demo contract... the warning/error looks like this:

[5/3/2021 2:29:19 PM] [WARNING] Could not get metadata for smart contract demo-contract. The smart contract may not have been developed with the programming model delivered in Hyperledger Fabric v1.4+ for Java, JavaScript and TypeScript. Error: Transaction function "org.hyperledger.fabric:GetMetadata" returned an error: Query failed. Errors: ["Peer org1peer-api.127-0-0-1.nip.io:8080: error in simulation: failed to execute transaction c387520943329acbfcb67d1639b63467791006d9e6464deaa491426b3d940337: could not launch chaincode demo-contract_0.0.1:6da187e384f13aa34360d36f2c645a793b7d811c32d4ae7b483d8519f312fa87: chaincode registration failed: failed to wait on container exit: builder 'node' run failed: exit status 1"]

I'm still a beginner in VS code and coding in general. So I'm not sure exactly what the error message means.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: The tutorial had me use TypeScript.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a programming model from: "Hyperledger Fabric v1.4", if you don't have this installed, perhaps you should try adding it to your project.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try that now!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, after many hours trying different things I realize that in the OUTPUT window, after deploying the smart contract a message like "smart contract PARTIALLY deployed - not commit" was displayed. So I decided to change the value in Step A2.5 (Tutorial A2) that indicates "Click 'TypeScript'", I selected 'JavaScript' then I got the following OUTPUT messages:

[5/5/2021 22:52:32] [SUCCESS] Successfully approved smart contract definition [5/5/2021 22:52:32] [INFO] commitSmartContract [5/5/2021 22:52:34] [SUCCESS] Successfully committed smart contract definition [5/5/2021 22:52:34] [SUCCESS] Successfully deployed smart contract

Now the transactions appear in the tree.

Comment: can you send me the tutorial you followed?

Comment: I can confirm that worked for me. I was using Typescript, as the tutorial recommended, and I had to start over using Javascript and it worked. @MahmoodH.Alnasser the tutorial can be found when you download the VS Code Extension for IBM Blockchain Platform.

Answer (score -1):

I tried with javascript and it worked, then I found another solution for typescript :

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Now, transactions are shown with smart contract using typescript option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).